# How to crawl website pages and search for specific text on all pages?

Tags: web-crawler

I am working on a web crawler using simple HTML DOM library. I have get all the links of a website. Now i want to crawl all the links/pages that i have get, search and find some specific text on all pages.

here is my code to get all the links

```
<?php

include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
set_time_limit(0);
$path='http://www.barringtonsports.com';
$html = file_get_contents($path);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++ ) {
$href = $hrefs->item($i);
$url = $href->getAttribute('href');
$nurl = $path.$url.'<br>';
echo $nurl; 
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some pseudo-code for you:

```
Create a list of $interestingURLs
Create a list of $matchingURLs
Call Search with your root site, Search("barringtonsports.com")
Search($site):
    1: append $site to $interestingURLs
    2: $searchedSites = 0
    3: for each ($entry in $interestingURLs):
        3a: SearchForSite($entry)
        3b: $searchedSites++
        3c: if ($searchedSites > MAX_SEARCHES):
            3c1: for each ($site in $matchingURLs) print $site

SearchForSite($site):
    1: load dom for $site
    2: search dom for interesting content, if exists - add $site to $matchingURLs
    3: extract all links
    4: for each link append to the end of $interestingURLs
```

Next order of business is to rank the list of machingURLs in relevance. One way would be to use a map/dictionary where the url is the index and the relevance rank is the value.

Good luck!